# Is this geometry problem wrong?

Tags: geometry

**Problem**

> Side $\overline{AB} = 3. \triangle{ABF}$ is an equilateral triangle. Side 
>   $\overline{DE} = \overline{AB} = \overline{AF} = \overline{GE}. \angle{FED} = 60^{\circ}. \overline{FG} = 1$. Calculate the area of $ABCDE$.

[image]

**Question**
Aren't there infinitely many $ABCDE$s? We can just keep moving $CD$ clockwise about $D$ and it still satisfies the conditions of the problem.

**Offical solution**

[image]

Comment: Why is it necessary for the problem-poser to stipulate that $AB = AF$ in the second line when we already know $\triangle ABF$ is equilateral? This kind of redundancy makes me suspicious of the problem-poser's competence. Usually you're given just enough non-redundant information to complete a problem/proof.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: 2000 Stanford math tournament.

Comment: Does the problem specify that G, C & D are collinear?

Comment: The proof refers to $\Delta FCDE$. That doesn't even make sense; $FCDE$ is not a triangle.

Answer (score 2):

If by moving CD clockwise, you mean sliding $C$ along the edge $FB$, yes. The problem is ill-posed. Perhaps D, C, and G are intended to be colinear?

Comment: How did they come to the conclusion that area of FCDE = area ABF-area FGC?

Comment: That also makes no sense.  It should be that area of ABCG = area ABF - area FGC.

Answer (score 0):

The points should A,F,G,E remain collinear or at some ppint the diagram will get inverted and as the collinearity is lost it'll be difficult to calculate areas of triangles